# Should a scrum team estimate time for the user stories during Sprint Planning, or before it?

Tags: agile, scrum

I am newbie for scrum. Lets say we have all the user stories for the product, and the product owner gave them the priorities. Now as a team, when we should estimate times for these stories? Should we estimate times for all the stories roughly before the sprint planning then updating them if it is necessary during sprint planning?

Actually I am curious which part of scrum first time estimation should be begin? During sprint planning or where?

Comment: Time is not the usual measure for user story estimation. It might be for *tasks* though. I recommend you update your question to reflect what you really mean by "estimate times for stories".

Answer (score 5):

Typically, teams hold [backlog grooming meetings](http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-backlog-grooming/) during a sprint to discuss and estimate the items in their backlog. Having at least the highest priority portion of the backlog estimated before the planning meeting makes planning for the next sprint go much more quickly. It lets the team focus on which items will be part of the next sprint rather than getting into the details of individual items.

Answer (score 1):

In the scrum process the tasks are estimated at the sprint planning meeting,

1. Product owner presents the top priority items from the backlog
2. Team does the effort estimations for each item
3. Depending on the time box certain items may be moved to the next sprint or more items may be added to the current sprint.

Read more from : http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/scrum/overview

Answer (score 0):

This should take place in the [planning game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming_practices#Planning_game). Armed with the estimates and business priorities, stories are selected for the upcoming sprint.